# hdf5 -- ValueError: Not a property list class (Not a property list class)

Tags: python, ubuntu, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

When I tried to train a network with caffe, I got the following error information:

```
....
layer {
  name: "sigmoid_speed"
  type: "Sigmoid"
  bottom: "fc8-final"
  top: "pred_speed"
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "pred_speed"
  bottom: "reshape-label"
  top: "loss"
}

I0215 20:39:01.273730 29855 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jcsu/workshop/rnn/caffe-jeff/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition/sequence_input_layer_drive.py", line 18, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from ._hl.base import is_hdf5, HLObject
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/base.py", line 79, in <module>
    dlapl = default_lapl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/base.py", line 66, in default_lapl
    lapl = h5p.create(h5p.LINK_ACCESS)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/_objects.c:2684)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/_objects.c:2642)
  File "h5py/h5p.pyx", line 135, in h5py.h5p.create (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/h5p.c:2726)
ValueError: Not a property list class (Not a property list class)
Done
```

Here is the related part of the caffe model file`**.prototxt`:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Python"
  top: "data"
  top: "label_speed"
  top: "clip_markers"
  python_param {
    module: "sequence_input_layer_drive"
    layer: "videoReadTrain_RGB"
  }
  include: { phase: TRAIN }
}

layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Python"
  top: "data"
  top: "label_speed"
  top: "clip_markers"
  python_param {
    module: "sequence_input_layer_drive"
    layer: "videoReadTest_RGB"
  }
  include: { phase: TEST stage: "test-on-test" }
}
```

To figure out the problem, I tried:

```
  $ python
  >>> import h5py
```

It succeeded.

Then I tried:

```
  python sequence_input_layer_drive.py
```

It also executed.

So I have been stuck...  Can anybody please help me?

Comment: I also ran into this issue. Did you ever figure it out?